# Is there a "natural" undecidable language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, computability, undecidability

Is there any "natural" language which is undecidable?

by "natural" I mean a language defined directly by properties of strings, and not via machines and their equivalent. In other words, if the language looks like
$$ L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \ldots \}$$
where $M$ is a TM, DFA (or regular-exp), PDA (or grammar), etc.., then $L$ **is not** natural. However $L = \{xy \ldots \mid x \text{ is a prefix of y} \ldots \}$ is natural.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you wanted "strings", I mention the classic one: [Post Correspondence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem).

Answer (score 21):

There are [many examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems) but here are a few:

- The set of true sentences in the language of [arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_order_arithmetic) is undecidable.
- The set of provable sentences in set theory (ZFC) is undecidable.
- The set of Diophantine equations which have solutions is undecidable.